# Django 1.4 project wide code ( template tags)

Tags: django, django-templates

With 1.4 round the corner I thought I would give it a go but I have a question about the new [project layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4-beta-1/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py).

```
manage.py
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
mysite/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

I can see the logic here and I am a fan of the new layout however if I am having issues with adding project wide code.

**For example:**
I have created a new templatetag that is specific to this project and doesn't fit logically fit in any one of my apps.  To me this should then fit within *mysite* however (as far as I can tell) this is not then processed.  *apptag.py* (see below) is available but *sitetag.py* is not.  Now, I am assuming this is because *mysite* not processed in the same way as an app(?).

```
manage.py
myapp/
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        apptag.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
mysite/
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        site.py
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

**My question** then is what is the right way to go about this issue?  Should I create an app called `'core'`, `'mysitecore'` or such like?  I can add `'mysite'` to INSTALLED_APPS but that just feels down right wrong.  Or is there another option that I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templatetags need to be inside an app that is included in INSTALLED_APPS. This is, in my opinion, a wart in Django that isn't fixed by the new layout. Your idea of using a `core` app - or, as I often do, `utils` - is the right one.